# Image Compression, Server or Phone?

Tags: user-expectation, design-patterns, mobile-application

Say a user wants to change his profile picture and uploads his 1920*1080 1mb picture.

That picture I want to process into 2 new ones

- One "HD" Version, which is still quite good, but file size reduced
  ~200kb
- One "Thumbnail" version, which is very small and low quality.
  ~50kb

Now I see 3 options on how to proceed:

1. Scale and Compress Original on the Android device, and then upload both to the server.
2. Send Original picture to the server and then have the server compress it to a thumbnail and hd version.
3. Compress Original to the "HD" version on device, and send that to the server, and have the server create a thumbnail off that.

I want the user experience (network usage, battery drain, etc) to be the best possible. Or is there an other and more efficient way altogether?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Battery is usually not that big issue but good internet connection is**. You want to keep uploading times and data being uploaded as little as possible.
2. **Rescaling images is not that heavy on processing power** (unless you are resizing a billboard sized photo) so it is safe to do it on your phone.

Following this logic I should say go with an option **(3)** but there is a catch. From developer side of view its not a good practice to split such a logic into two different subsystems (client and server). It is making updates tough to manage.

So **Go with an option (1)**. Rescaling and uploading a thumbnail sized image is not that big of a drag and you will keep your developers happy.